# SQL Join Tables - transports and locations

Tags: sql, join

Updated description to make it easier to understand.

It has been a long time for me not working with SQL statements and it looks like a simple thing knocks me down^^

I have a table "transports" which has following columns:

- locations_fromid
- locations_toid
- transport_number
- distance
- ...

A second table "locations" contains following columns:

- id
- city
- country
- zip
- ...

transports.locations_fromid and transports.locations_toid referencing to locations.id (foreign key)

Questions:
1) How can I create a view, that shows me all (*) from transports plus the city of origin and the city of destination.

2) Assuming we have n transports in the transport table with the same transport_number. How can I create a view that aggregates all transports distinctively with all citys touched.

Example row:
123456, Hamburg, New York, New York, Washington, Washington, Denver, 10,000km
(transportnumber, fromid, toid, fromid, toid, fromid, toid, sum (distance)

In this example we agregated 3 lines in the table transports that have the same transport_number

I feels like the answers to my questions are simple but i wasn't able to google it myself.

Many thanks
Adam

Comment: can u post create statement and sample data

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your first question:
I believe this should work

```
SELECT transports.*, FromCity.City, ToCity.City FROM transports 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations FromCity ON transports.fromid = Locations.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations ToCity ON transports.toid = Locations.id
```

Is the '1122' in the second question an id on the transports table?

Comment: SELECT 
 transports.*, FromCity.adress_city SOURCE, ToCity.adress_city  DESTINATION
 FROM  
 transports
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 locations FromCity 
 ON 
 transports.locations_fromid = FromCity.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 locations ToCity 
 ON 
 transports.locations_toid = ToCity.id

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT 
 transports.*, FromCity.adress_city SOURCE, ToCity.adress_city  DESTINATION
 FROM  
 transports
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 locations FromCity 
 ON 
 transports.locations_fromid = FromCity.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 locations ToCity 
 ON 
 transports.locations_toid = ToCity.id
```

That solved my first question. Thanks to @happyChap